# np.einsum performance of 4 matrix multiplications

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

Given the following 3 matrices:

```
M = np.arange(35 * 37 * 59).reshape([35, 37, 59])
A = np.arange(35 * 51 * 59).reshape([35, 51, 59])
B = np.arange(37 * 51 * 51 * 59).reshape([37, 51, 51, 59])
C = np.arange(59 * 27).reshape([59, 27])
```

I'm using `einsum` to compute:

```
D1 = np.einsum('xyf,xtf,ytpf,fr->tpr', M, A, B, C, optimize=True);
```

But I found it to be much less performant then:

```
tmp = np.einsum('xyf,xtf->tfy', A, M, optimize=True)
tmp = np.einsum('ytpf,yft->ftp', B, tmp, optimize=True)
D2 = np.einsum('fr,ftp->tpr', C, tmp, optimize=True)
```

And I can't understand why.
Overall I'm trying to optimize this piece of code as much as I can. I've read about the `np.tensordot` function but I can't seem to figure out how to utilize it for the given computation.

Comment: That looks good already. You could use tensordot at the last step for possibly some improvement, but that's not the bottleneck, so won't change the timings much.

Comment: But how come splitting `einsum` to 3 yields better results? And what is the bottleneck, then?

Comment: Well the bottleneck seems to be the first two steps of the second method (D2). `"But how come splitting einsum to 3 yields better results"` - Don't know the reason, but my observation when working with einsum has been that when working with more number of inputs einsum becomes slow, specially with tensors. If I have to guess, I would think its memory congestion, like here we would have 6 loops in the D1 method.

Comment: @Divakar `optimize=True` will split the contraction into multiple smaller contractions to lower overall scaling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you stumbled onto a case where the `greedy` path gives a non-optimal scaling.

```
>>> path, desc = np.einsum_path('xyf,xtf,ytpf,fr->tpr', M, A, B, C, optimize="greedy");
>>> print(desc)
  Complete contraction:  xyf,xtf,ytpf,fr->tpr
         Naive scaling:  6
     Optimized scaling:  5
      Naive FLOP count:  3.219e+10
  Optimized FLOP count:  4.165e+08
   Theoretical speedup:  77.299
  Largest intermediate:  5.371e+06 elements
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
scaling                  current                                remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   5              ytpf,xyf->xptf                         xtf,fr,xptf->tpr
   4               xptf,xtf->ptf                              fr,ptf->tpr
   4                 ptf,fr->tpr                                 tpr->tpr

>>> path, desc = np.einsum_path('xyf,xtf,ytpf,fr->tpr', M, A, B, C, optimize="optimal");
>>> print(desc)
  Complete contraction:  xyf,xtf,ytpf,fr->tpr
         Naive scaling:  6
     Optimized scaling:  4
      Naive FLOP count:  3.219e+10
  Optimized FLOP count:  2.744e+07
   Theoretical speedup:  1173.425
  Largest intermediate:  1.535e+05 elements
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
scaling                  current                                remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4                xtf,xyf->ytf                         ytpf,fr,ytf->tpr
   4               ytf,ytpf->ptf                              fr,ptf->tpr
   4                 ptf,fr->tpr                                 tpr->tpr
```

Using `np.einsum('xyf,xtf,ytpf,fr->tpr', M, A, B, C, optimize="optimal")` should have you running at peak performance. I can look into this edge to see if greedy can nab it.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is true that a greedy algorithm (there are several) may not find the optimal ordering in this case, this does not have anything to do with the puzzle here. When you do the D2 approach you have determined the order of operations which in this case is (((A,M),B),C) or equivalently (((M,A),B),C). This happens to be the optimal path. The 3 optimize=True statements are not needed and are ignored because there is no optimization used when there are 2 factors. The slowdown of the D1 method is due to the need to find the optimal ordering of a 4 array operation. If you first found the path and then passed it, with the 4 arrays, to einsum using Optimize=path my guess is that the two methods would be essentially equivalent. Thus the slowdown is due to the optimization step for D1. Although I am not sure how the optimal ordering is found, based on unpublished work I've done, this task will generally have O(3^n) worst case behavior where n is the number of arrays.